How do I solve the 4-way puzzle in the Great Caves?
In Swordigo, how do I solve the 4-way puzzle in the Great Caves? With that problem, I am unable to complete my next journey in the game...

Hi Naira, can you be a bit more specific, and perhaps post a screenshot? What do you need to do exactly?

This is the solution:

upper left
lower left
lower right
upper right

Here's a video reference:



